# How to return a value from one column of a df if the value of another column is found in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with 2 columns, `A` and `B`, and then a list of values called `C`.
I need my code to check whether each value in `df.B` is in list `C`, and for all that are `True` then return the corresponding values from `df.A` to a list.

I've tried using a `for` loop, and later found the `.isin()` function but just can't figure out how to utilize either of these in a way that'll give me the result I need.

Comment: Please share the corresponding, simplified code on that issue. Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide an example of your data and the expected output. A visual example is much better than a lengthy description of your data.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4865723) will help you, too.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df.loc[df['B'].isin(C), 'A'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use a loop when you can select things natively with pandas.

```
df[df.B.isin(C)].A.to_list()
```

If the `B` name is not a single word (e.g. `COLUMN NAME`), use:

```
df[df['B'].isin(C)]['A'].to_list()
```

`df.B.isin(C)` will return a Series of True/False depending on whether the values in B are in C. Then use this to select the rows in the original dataframe. Finally, select the column `A` and convert to list.

Comment: I don't use slicing by attribute. Not just when a column name contains whitespace, but there may be name collisions with names like 'max' and such; some of which may occur in future versions of the DataFrame class. So my code would break when they add a new attribute.  Using `loc`, `iloc` and the regular python `[]` slicing syntax doesn't have that problem.

Comment: I fully agree, I actually always use `[]` in my own code.